# Git Hub - set up a second location to work from

Tags: git

I appreciate there is a wealth of information about Git, but being new to it all those searches have resulted in posts that have been overwhelming and contradicting opinions and best practices. I am I hope trying to achieve something relatively simple, just looking for a clear and concise advice on getting me started.

Working on an internal website site from my local drive and have set it up as a repository (Git Bash'd from the folder and ran a

```
  git commit -m "<Message>"
  git push -u origin master
```

to get it copied online. I now need to copy/clone/pull (??) this down to a second location (on the same machine) but on a network drive, this is the live location for this content. I am hoping ongoing I will be working from my local drive and pulling down changes to the live folder when i need to. I hope this is the correct way to go about it, but I can't for the life of me work out the correct way to do so ?

Kind regards

Comment: so what do you have problems with? why don't normal pull work?

Answer (score 0):

So go to that location. Then git clone your repository there and you are able to pull in all new changes.